# Use Powershell to Search Microsoft Word .docx Document and Display Text Surrounding Search String

Tags: powershell, search, ms-word, full-text-search

Using only Powershell, how does one display the surrounding x lines above or below a search string in a Microsoft Word .docx document?

I'm able to use Powershell to query the Word document and find my string.  But I don't know how to get the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing you script it's hard to comment, knowing what version of powershell and the cmdlets you're using will help answer the question better.

If you're using [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1) you can use -Context to return lines above and below your match

From the MS documentation:

```
Select-String -Path "audit.log" -Pattern "logon failed" -Context 2, 3
```

Would give you 2 lines above and 3 lines below the match.